# Change colour of selected <li>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following `HTML` code:

```html
<div class="MenuContainer">
  <div class="Menu">
    <div class="MenuContents">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="gamePage.html">Game</a></li>
        <li><a href="gameDesignPage.html">Game Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="devRolesPage.html">Developer Roles</a></li>
        <li class="float-right"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make it so that when one of the list items is selected the background colour changes even after the `href` loads the new selected page therefore making it clear to the user what page they are on?

I have read many answers to similar stack overflow questions that generally use `JQuery` to add a `css` `class` to the `html` list item or anchor when clicked that changes the colour but it does not work for me, I feel like because the `href` changes the page (loads a new page) everything is reset each time I select a list item and the colour never changes or perhaps only does so for a split second and I cant notice it?

Comment: Change the background of the element when its inner `<a>` has a `href` attribute that matches the current `window.location.href`.

Answer (score 2):

Since I can't comment (Don't have 50 rep points yet) I'll make it as an answer with what I think what you are trying to achieve.

You want the page that is currently active to have a different background color?
why not add a class to the active page he is on?

For example:

js

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
switch(pathname) {
   case "/index" :
       var active = document.getElementById("Home");
       active.ClassName += " Active";
       break;
   case "/gamePage" :
       var active = document.getElementById("GamePage");
       active.ClassName += " Active";
       break;
}
```

css

```
.Active{
   background-color: black;
}
```

html

```
                <li><a id="Index" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a id="GamePage" href="gamePage.html">Game</a></li>
                <li><a id="GameDesignPage" href="gameDesignPage.html">Game Design</a></li>
                <li><a id="DevRolesPage" href="devRolesPage.html">Developer Roles</a></li>
                <li id="About" class="float-right"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
```

Comment: Nemoko, this is a correct solution. However this is bad practice and needs a lot of work to maintain it (example: When adding a new item). Also maybe this persons includes the same navigation which would make your solution incorrect. However, i'm going to upvote because it's nicely formulated :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however the issue is this - of course I can manually add a css class to the elements and it would change its colour, but I need this to happen automatically as the user navigates my site by clicking the list items, I cannot manually add classes to the list items as the user clicks them in real time, does that make sense? I believe it has to happen by using some sort of JavaScript.

Comment: Programming is not about copy-pasting code and adding a case for every scenario, specially when working with *N* - but to derive a logical process that can handle an indefinite number of cases - with a special exception for index page (which does not necessarily contain the `"index"` string)

Answer (score 2):

First you need the pathname of the url. I also delete the leading slash:

```
var path = window.location.pathname.substring(1);
```

If you have .html in your files, replace it by using substring again:

```
path = path.substring(0, path.length - 5);
```

To achieve an easy way for javascript, add id's with the same name to your a links

```
<a id="index" href="index.html">Home</a>
```

Now mix them together:

```
var activeLink = document.getElementById(path);
```

Now add the active class you want:

```
activeLink.classList.add("active");
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer from Wimanicesir, I have managed to solve the issue.

I now have the html code:

```
<div class="MenuContainer">
    <div class="Menu">
        <div class="MenuContents">
            <ul>
                <li><a id="index" href="index.html" >Home</a></li>
                <li><a id="gamePage" href="gamePage.html" >Game</a></li>
                <li><a id="gameDesignPage" href="gameDesignPage.html" >Game Design</a></li>
                <li><a id="devRolesPage" href="devRolesPage.html" >Developer Roles</a></li>
                <li class="float-right"><a id="about" href="about.html" >About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var path = window.location.pathname.substring(1);
    path = path.substring(0, path.length - 5);
    var pathShort = path.substring(path.indexOf("/")+1);
    var activeLink = document.getElementById(pathShort);
    activeLink.classList.add("active");
});
```

And this now works, thanks for the push in the right direction Wimanicesir.